# Remote desktop not working for Pi 3 Model B+

Tags: pi-3, remote, pi-3b+

I am trying to get remote desktop to work on my Pi 3 B+, but it is not working. This is the code I have used:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove xrdp vnc4server tightvncserver

$ sudo apt-get install tightvncserver

$ sudo apt-get install xrdp
```

These are the screens that I am getting on my mac's Remote Desktop.

[image]

When I clicked the button, this is the screen that it takes me to.

[image]

Where do I go from here?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I used the VNC-Server-6.2.0-Linux-ARM.deb package from Raspbian and installed it on a Pi 3 B w/ubuntu-16.04 Ma'te desktop.
I then installed realVNC server on my [custom] DZ68DB w/ubuntu-16.04 Gnome 3.
All installations went fine and I am now running a Pi 3 B firewall/router as a headless system.

Answer (score 0):

The last image in your post is the login panel I also get. Assuming that you can type in the boxes, what I do to connect to my raspberry from here is:

1.select "Xorg" in the first line;
2.The second line is for the username;
3.The 3rd line is for the password;

P.S: if you didn't change the login details, the defaults are

name: 'pi'

password: 'raspberry'

Comment: The last image is all I see. It would let me type in, but I wouldn't be able to select Xorg. The drop-down menu is completely blank.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used `xrdp` which, I understand,  is a Windows protocol, and presumably relies on `X` which is **NOT** installed on `macOS`.

`xrdp`, `tightvncserver` and `RealVNC` are **ALL** `VNC` servers, but are **mutually exclusive**.

`tightvncserver` and `RealVNC` are both usable on the Mac, but operate somewhat differently (`RealVNC` requires its own client, which includes `X`)

I use `tightvncserver`, which you can connect from the Mac screen client with `open vnc://pi@raspberrypi.local:5901`

`tightvncserver` requires some setup on the Pi, and I have posted answers on how to start on boot. `RealVNC` requires setup to use headless.